# Laravel Controllers Structure And Numbers of Controller

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

Question1: I have controllers structure like :

```
-http
 -controllers
  --admin
     -controlle_1...n
  --user
     -controlle_1...n
  --Front View
     -controlle_1...n
```

Is it okay ? What are the good practices.

Question 2: Let suppose i have a countroller `CityController` So for `admin` i am inserting records for `User` i am fetching those records and same for `Front View`. So i should have one controller for all of those or should i have separate controller like for `User`,`Admin`,`Front View`.

I am working on E commerce Application so i have 15 Controllers.

What are the good practices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice would be to separate your business logic from the controllers. So essentially you have a separate set of classes dealing with the business logic.

**./Service/ItemService.php**

```
namespace Service;

class ItemService
{
    public function create($name, $description, $active = true)
    {
        $itemRepository = new ItemRepository();

        $item = $itemRepository->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description,
            'active' => $active,
        ]);

        // Create audit log
        $log = new AuditLogService;
        $log->create("New product was created", $item);

        // Update stock

        // Send notification email, etc.

        return $item;
    }
}
```

**./Repository/ItemRepository.php**

```
namespace Repository;

class ItemRepository
{
    public function create($data)
    {
        $item = new Item;
        $item->fill($data);
        $item->save();

        return $item;
    }
}
```

**./Controller/FrontEnd/ItemController.php**

```
namespace Controller\FrontEnd;

class ItemController
{
    public function store()
    {
        // Validate data

        // Call service to create item
        $itemService = new ItemService;
        $item = $itemService->create($request->inputs);

        // return view response
    }
}
```

**./Controller/Admin/ItemController.php**

```
namespace Controller\Admin;

class ItemController
{
    public function store()
    {
        // Validate data

        // Call service to create item
        $itemService = new ItemService;

        $item = $itemService->create($request->inputs);

        // return JSON response
    }
}
```

As you can see multiple controllers can reuse the core business logic. This will help you a great deal in code reusing and maintainability.

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks

Comment: @Gamer Anytime! Also, I'm working on a base library for similar applications Still WIP but you'll be able to get a broader idea. https://github.com/devrtips/php-soa-library.

Comment: Great... Will be in touch. Any way on which i can contact ?

Comment: @Gamer sure my email address is in my github profile, drop me an email anytime!

Comment: Great ! Will be in touch